# Meaning of "on a city lot and a half"

Tags: expressions

Can anyone teach me the meaning of the following expression I came across on home-for-sale websites?

The house/home is situated/sits on a city lot and a half.

I've image-searched the expression, which showed some sort of isolated-but-decent looking flat buildings (not all of them, though), but I'm not sure if the expression means like that.

Comment: It sounds like it occupies 1.5 city lots.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence, I thought it was referring  to the appearance of the building. Glad I've asked, thank you for your help.